# How to fix error UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8 codec can't decode byte in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: utf-8, raspberry-pi, serial-port, gps, python-unicode

I am not a programmer and I am trying to use a serial GPS module with RPi 4B.
When I run the Python code, most of the time I get the error message, probably because when the serial is opened my GPS module almost always sends some crazy '0x--' style bytes before the NMEA sentences, which crashes the program. It happens 90% of the time I try to run the program, but seldom it works.
It has to do with the code, but I have no clue, so I request the community's help to fix that. Thanks!
Code:

```py
import io
import pynmea2
import serial
import datetime


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 9600, timeout=0.5)
sio = io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedRWPair(ser, ser))

while 1:
    try:
        line = sio.readline()
        msg = pynmea2.parse(line)
        
        if (msg.sentence_type == 'GGA'):
                ts = datetime.datetime.now()
                lat = msg.latitude
                lon = msg.longitude
                alt = msg.altitude
                gps = str(ts) + "|" + str(lat) + "|" + str(lon) + "|" + str(alt) 
                print (gps)
        
    except serial.SerialException as e:
        print('Device error: {}'.format(e))
        break
```

Error I get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/GRC/GPS_Rx1.py", line 12, in <module>
    line = sio.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: In TextIOWrapper use an encoding, e.g. `, encoding="cp1252"` (0x96 is probably not `Latin1`), or `, encoding="utf-8", errors="backslashreplace"`. Or just traeat is as binary code as it is effectively (using ASCII convention, but the values are fixed)

Comment: Drop the io wrapper, do a direct read of the raw bytes and see what you are actually receiving.  What’s the spec for the device?